# Filter rows by using awk in bash

Tags: awk

I have a file containing 11 columns with 600 entries. The column no 6 is based on some values ranging -5 to + 10. I want to just pull out entries with less than or equal to -0.2 and greater or equal to +0.2
I know awk can do filtering. But facing difficulties to write proper syntax to pull out my desire data.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a finished solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51393338/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your delimiter, so you'll have to modify the following with `-F<your_delimiter>`.

```
awk '$6 <= -0.2 || $6 >= 0.2'
```

Comment: Surely you mean `awk '$6 <= -0.2 || $6 >= 0.2'`? :) (I know, I tested on `$2` as well, because screw making 6-column test file... :p )

Comment: @Amadan, Yes, I did. Brain fart.

Comment: It solves in some extent. But my initial file wasn't a proper csv file. I made it by using sed command. The above command works only on column 6 when I cut the field no 6 by 'cut' command. But, it didn't work for the whole file to pull the rows within this range.

Comment: @user266095, It sounds like you have a related but different question. Please ask that as a separate question.